# Calculate actual time from different timezones in php

Tags: php, html, datetime

Hai,

I would like to calculate actual time from different timezones. 
I have two mysql tables

1.Timezone table: 
This table contians two fields (offset value, country name) 
values are ( -12:00, Eniwetok, Kwajalein) (-11:00, Midway Island, Samoa).... so on

2.My employee table 
This table contains the employees details with two field names (created_on, timezone) and the values are  (current timestamp, -11:00) (current timestamp, -12:00)..... so on

Now, If my employee logged in to my system, i want to display the time according to their timezones values from tables.

Basically if my 
Current timestamp is :2010-05-10 15:41:39
offset values is: +5:30

my result should be : 10 May 2010 3:41pm

the same for different offset values for the same current timestamp. I believe i explained the issue correctly, if you want any information, please ask me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is [date_default_timezone_set()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.phpBlockquote)

> date_default_timezone_set() sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions

Comment: In my experience, setting the timezone both in mysql (see the other answer) and php is enough to have the correct times for users around the world. If this is not the case, you should consider creating a custom date function which increments or decrements passed timestamps based on the current user's timezone before outputting the formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `timestamp` datatype to store all dates in your application
2. for each employee keep it's timezone in format of timezone name. Ex: "Asia/Vladivostok"
3. After employee is identified just after mysql_connect - send yet another query to specify which timezone is used now. This can be done with mysql query `SET time_zone=TZ`, where `TZ` const is time shift like "+10:00" or if you're lucky and your mysql server has timezones collection imported - more correct way like: "Asia/Vladivostok" (`SET time_zone="Asia/Vladivostok"`)
4. Also - don't forget to specify php's timezone with `ini_set('date.timezone', TZ)` or already mentioned `date_default_timezone_set()`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an underlying problem with your data.

The employee table contains fixed timezone offsets for past events - presumably when the profiles were created - but these can't necessarily be used to determine offsets for future events, as many locations use daylight saving time (DST).

The timezone table seems redundant at the moment, as there is no way you can cross-reference against employees. And again, offsets will change due to DST.

You would normally store the location for each user in your database, then use something like `date_default_timezone_set()` that to display times correctly for that location.