# Worldclock(s) PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Timezone conversion in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Looking for a script to display a number of different time (zones) on a site - flash can do this but has become obsolete due to Apple and the JavaScript I have found all miss the daylight savings adjustment functionality.

Script/plugin needs to be un-styled for site branding purposes. Site = PHP

Comment: sounds like you're just asking for a free script, not some coding help..

Comment: *(reference)* [PHP Manual: DateTime](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Comment: *(related)* [Timezone Conversion in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Comment: Thanks Gordon!
Nathan, your supposition doesn't do you much good..

Comment: Just to pick on the `Site = PHP`. Your site is called PHP and powered by PHP? That's in violations to PHP license http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_License#Terms ;)

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a dumb answer, but what's wrong with calculating them yourself? Shouldn't all timezones be off from the previous by exactly one hour?
Daylight savings time is the same - add or remove one hour, unless I'm missing something vital here :)

Of course if you need to display the timezone by city, it would be quite a hassle.

Comment: DST is not that simple. For instance, Japan doesn't have it - and you have to know about it. If you blindly adjust for it everywhere, you'll get wrong results half the time.