# Javascript: How do I convert a specific timezoned date to different time zone date?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, date

I have a php script which gives server time, but as per knowledge, we can get the user's machine time and time zone with the help of client side scripts (javascript). I have mysql table which has dates stored along with timezone from where it was stored with the help of form. I need to show the data on a web page along with the time stored in the table, but it should be per user's machine.

```
rowid | date | timezone | data |
----------------------------------
12  | 2010-07-13 12:30:00 | Asia/Kolkata | This is data field |
143 | 2010-07-13 12:30:00 | Europe/Prague | This is data field |
```

Now, when I show date on web page, I need to show the above date per user's machine timezone.

A workaround logic would be that, if I could pass the date (2010-07-13 12:30:00) to some JS method which will take two time zone as input and convert the given  date into user's machine's timezone. Or Something else?

Please help?

Comment: So I suppose a PHP solution is out of the question?

Comment: *(related)* [Timezone Conversion in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php/2505687#2505687) - in case you decide not to do it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

See the following link:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php

You can set the timezone in the script before displaying the dates although make sure you insert all the times in the DB as GMT.

Comment: How do I get visitor's timezone with php? 

It can be done with javascript only I think?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the best way is to use javascript and then maybe have an ajax function push it to a session var. I have managed to do this many years ago with PHP using their IP Address and getting the details of that but was a huge headache