# How to get the time of a given city?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, web-services, time

I know that I can display time for a particular location using only JavaScript (and no web service or external data source), but...
I want to avoid using this solution because I don't want to have to account for daylight savings time, and any other factors that make it complicated.

I'm looking for an easier way to display the time and always for a particular city (or zip code, or whatever identifier works...).

For example, I want a page to always say:

**The current time in Miami is "X"**

(where "X" should be replaced by the current time in Miami)

Is there a web service (or any other method) where I can post some identifier (city name, zip code, etc) and get back the time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate: The point here is to find out the time zone of a given location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a web service (or any other method) where I can post some identifier (city name, zip code, etc) and get back the time?

I don't know of a *single* web service that will do the job.

Google's [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) can help.  You can feed it a parameter, and it will return certain information, such as the latitude/longitude.  [Example using a zip code](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=95037&sensor=false), but I'm sure you can easily put in a city/state pair and make it work.

You can then take that lat/long pair and point it at service like [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/).  They have a [timezone API](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone) that takes a lat/long pair and returns quite a bit of information.  [Example using the lat/long from the zip code.](http://ws.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=37.2187714&lng=-121.5826642)