#  How to convert local time to UTC format?

Tags: php, datetime, utc

I have date

```
$timeZome = timezone_open('Europe/Kiev');
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone($timeZome);
$date->setDate(2011, 06,25);
$date->setTime(11,35,00);
```

How to present like that?

```
20110625T040000Z
```

Comment: this may be an international thing but what does the "T040000Z
" part of your date represent?

Comment: "T040000Z" is just an example

Comment: so its the timestamp? what do the T and Z represent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Kiev'));
$date->setDate(2011, 06,25);
$date->setTime(11,35,00);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo $date->format('Ymd\THis\Z'); // format string to match question
```

It's pretty straightforward: set the date/time/zone, modify the timezone and format for printing.

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to call [format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) on your date object, I think.

```
echo $date->format('Ymd'); // 20110625
```

**UPDATE:**
You may want to look into either using [the existing constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) in the date class, or if your needs differ from what date offers, simply extend it and add a method that parses and returns your date formatted as you want it to.

Comment: Can I convert a date, but I do not understand how to convert time in UTC format.