# Daylight saving issues

Tags: php, algorithm, datetime, date, dst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Daylight saving time and Timezone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)

Basically I have the following problem:

I have a table with all the GMT offsets and based on that I calculated the users hour relative to the servers hour but some are off by an hour.

So my function looks like this, it takes GMT+/-3600*usersTZ(GMT offset).
London looks ok, Australia looks ok, but hey Samoa, instead of being eg: 5 it`s 6.

I figured that might be the case with daylight saving, any ideeas?

Comment: [PHP's DateTime and strtotime are DST aware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php/2505687#2505687). Use them instead.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but please ask questions before answering like a forum robot :p. I've already checked the above topics, strtotime is not working, Samoa time is not showing correctly for 'Pacific/Samoa' timezone in strtotime, now it should be 9:01pm Monday (WST), which I think is rather akward because Samoa is GMT -11 which makes it 10pm. And besides, I need to do that based on the TZ of each client

Comment: then I wonder why you accepted the answer that suggested what I suggested right from the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can handle timezones natively. You just need to set timezone in [olson format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) like America/New_York.

You can then use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) or any other php DateTime stuff that understands timezones.

It would be very helpful to peruse the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) a little. Especially [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: Yes but wouldn`t that change all the date and time behaviour of all date and time functions in the entire script, where I can only modify only one function and besides, this is not my server and changing functionality to suite my needs as a developer is not an option.

Comment: That was just an example of a simple way to do it. You can use the `DateTime` class instead which takes a `DateTimeZone` object as a parameter.
As I said before, I _strongly_ recommend you read through the docs.

Comment: Tried that, but it says it does not recognize the class and I`m afraid that means the PHP wasn`t compiled with that in mind. Don`t have the luxury of recompiling PHP.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? This has been built in since version 5.2.0...

Comment: Thanks, problem solved :), you`ve got my vote