# php Datetime from format with Timezome

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to create a DateTime objet but with a specific DateTimeZone (the server could have it own DateTimeZone). Suppose the following string:

```
$textoFecha = '15-30-10-2012'; //H-d-m-Y
```

If I try to do this:

```
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('H-d-m-Y', $textoFecha);
$fecha->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("America/Costa_Rica"));
```

The result of make `echo $fecha->format('H-d-m-Y')` is:

```
19-30-10-2012
```

My question is, how can I set the DateTimeZome but keeping the giving values? (15-30-10-2012)

Comment: Coming from the DB? use `CONVERT_TZ`, Otherwise, dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php

Comment: The value of `$textoFecha` come from URL

Comment: Mmm, `date_default_timezone_set('America/Costa_Rica');` sounds good. I will test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the timezone in `DateTime::createFromFormat`, like this:

```
$textoFecha = '15-30-10-2012'; //H-d-m-Y
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('H-d-m-Y', $textoFecha, new DateTimeZone("America/Costa_Rica"));
echo $fecha->format('H-d-m-Y'); // prints 15-30-10-2012
```

Working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dqHDLW

Comment: That is exactly the parameter that I was needed! Thank so much :)