# Date does not change from UTC PHP

Tags: php, date

The code below will not give me the time in the timezone I specify. Why

```
    $dateTimeStr = substr($this->statsGW->fetchLatestDateTime(), 0, -7);
    $defaultTZ = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Rome");
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
    date("H:i",strtotime($dateTimeStr));
```

Instead it keeps returning the UTC time that is stored in the database and is fetched with the first code.

Comment: The date is stored in the DB, the UTC time ? Than you cant change it with new DateTimeZone or set default timezone. You have to store the correct date in the DB or calculate it manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Comment: It is stored in UTC in the DB. I have tried to set the default timezone but it always returns the date as stored in the dB

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify default time zone before get the date.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
$today = getdate();
print_r($today);
```

You can access any attribute of date object using $today vairable.

Comment: But the date is stored in the database and I retrieve it as string from it. Then I change it with strtotime and I have set the default_timezone_set before I do that but nothing.

Comment: Do you need to convert UTC time to Your declared time zone? If it is you can add or subtract time deference to UTC time.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing but I was wondering why the solution I have posted does not work