# How to calculate GMT and UTC timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp, utc, localtime

I have been using php/ mysql for long time and i have been using unix_timestamp to store date,time values. I have created timestamp class to handle this kind of request. Source code is available on [github](https://github.com/narayangt/scTimestamp).

By default, this class uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] which is GMT timestamp, I believe.

My requirement are to find out Local timestamp in accordance with GMT and show to user. In other word, I need to find the local time of any user and difference with GMT in number of seconds using PHP

How do I implement these requirements in my class.
Please help

Comment: GMT == UTC (timewise that is), so I guess you don't have any work (GMT is a timezone, UTC the standard of which the base time is the one from the GMT timezone)

Comment: How to get difference of GMT and user's region using PHP

Comment: You should update your question to reflect the change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` allows you to easily accomplish this:

```
// Interpret the time as UTC
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$datetime = new DateTime('@' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'], $timezone);

// Output as PHP's timezone
$user_timezone = new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()); // Or whatever timezone you need
$datetime->setTimeZone($user_timezone);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I got "2015-07-07 16:20:09" as result but, in my local time is "2015-07-08 02:20:09". How do i code my class so that the class would work for any region in world and prints local time

Comment: You change the part with the $user_timezone to the name of the users' timezone. You probably get that information from their account on your site, if you have them select a timezone.

Comment: is there any way to find out without asking user? if possible in PHP otherwise in jquery or javascript. Coz once I know the difference, it can be stored in connection database

Comment: Seriously... https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+determine+user+timezone You can at least do SOME effort.

Answer (score 0):

To get an UTC timestamp try:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

Comment: I did as following : 

$test=new scTimestamp();
$test1= new scTimestamp();

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$time= time();
$test1->setTimestamp($time);
echo $test->getDateTimeAsString();

echo $test1->getDateTimeAsString();

and get the same result: 

July 7, 2015, 4:10 pm
July 7, 2015, 4:10 pm

and my local time is July 8, 2015, 2:10 am