# Add +4GMT for php

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add +4GMT to the below

```
<?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i a");?>
```

Or anything can help to add the current time and date

Comment: Your question has already been asked. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2505687/2223027

Comment: Are you trying to convert to a different timezone or are you trying to add the timezone and offset to the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use time() to get the current time in seconds (UNIX) and add 3600*4.

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", time()+3600*4);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and put timezone accordingly which is gmt +4

```
<?php 
$dateTime = new DateTime(); 
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); 
return $dateTime->format('T'); 
?>
```