# How to convert string with T to a specific Timezone?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

So, if I have a string like so:  '2017-12-01T16:03:00' and need to convert this string into the timezone of `America/New_York`, how to convert this string?  Not exactly sure what the `T` is doing in the string and what it's for exactly.

I'm curious on the correct method for this, while I believe the `T` here is important, I understand the purpose of it.  What I've tried here so far:

```
$string = '2017-12-01T16:03:00';
$time_fix = explode('T', $string);

if (count($time_fix) > 1)
{
    $data_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_fix[0] . ' ' . $time_fix[1]);
    $output = $data_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
} else {
    $data_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_fix[0] . ' 00:00:00');
    $output = $data_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
}
```

Not really sure if this is converting the timezone or not, so wondering on what your thoughts are on this?  Will the `$output` variable contain the date and time for the `America/New_York` timezone?  It is very difficult to test this as I don't know what timezone it is currently in when the time string gets created.

Also, wondering if the T here is important and what it means.  And how to do this properly for the `America/New_York` timezone?

**UPDATE**

Apparently, I found out that the Server Timezone that is creating these Date strings via the API is in Eastern Standard Time already.  But if I didn't know this, how would it be converted to UTC?  The developers of the API, states that it is UTC in 8601 format, but the timezone is EST.  This does not make sense to me.  Because, I believe EST is UTC-5, not just UTC.  How the heck am I supposed to know this from what seems to be an improperly handled UTC timezone string result from the API?  Am I correct in stating that `2017-12-01T16:03:00` is not the correct string for EST timezone from a UTC timezone?

Comment: looks like an **[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)** format, which is by default UTC time zone. Just create a `$date = new DateTime($string)`, and set time zone to UTC with `$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));`

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - Are you suggesting that I do the following to convert it to my timezone from UTC:  `$date = new DateTime($info['CreateDate']);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$output = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do:

```
$date = new DateTime($info['CreateDate']); 
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC')); 
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 
$output = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You are first creating the DateTime object in your default timezone which will affect the timestamp calculation, and then changing the timezone. 
Instead, assuming UTC input, you should do:

```
$date = new DateTime($info['CreateDate'], new DateTimeZone('UTC')); 
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 
$output = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This way the DateTime object will interpret the input date as UTC time and correctly compute the timestamp. Then setting the timezone is just to get the right date string, it does not affect the underlying timestamp.

I notice that ISO 8601 date strings can specify UTC offsets so in this particular case you may get away without specifying it as no offset is given. This will also make no difference in this case if your default timezone is UTC.

Edit based on new data:

If you know the input is in Eastern Standard Timezone try changing the line where you construct the DateTime object.

```
$date = new DateTime($info['CreateDate'], new DateTimeZone('EST')); 
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 
$output = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Ok, I found out now that the API is strangely using Eastern Standard Timezone, but is returning a string like `2017-12-01T16:03:00`  So, I'm not sure how converting to UTC, and into `America/New_York` will give me EST from converting it into a datetime object.  Update, also found out that the last 2 numbers after the last `:` are always `:00`, so I don't know if this is the correct format (ISO 8601) or not now.

Answer (score 0):

Explode separate your `$string` the elements on `2017-12-01` and `16:03:45`.
And here you have the answer [Timezone conversion in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Comment: But I don't know what timezone it is initially in.  The answer that you pointed to is setting an initial timezone to `Europe\London` before it converts it into another timezone.

Comment: so you can use  `const tzid = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;` this to find client localize

Comment: This string is coming from an API call, so I doubt that will work.