# PHP LONDON time to INDIA time change

Tags: php

i want to change GMT time to INDIAN time,i will add 5:30 or 4:30

```
$INDtime=$time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('IST'));//uk time
 $time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('IST'));/india time
```

Comment: `IST` is not a supported timezone identifier. cf. http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: you will probably have to use  "Europe/London" time zone  and  "Asia/Kolkata"

Comment: have a look at this too.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/2505687/1471352

Comment: Thank you developersm,i found answers and i was finished by task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

echo "The Current time is:".time();
```

Comment: Thank you rimadsa,your answer very helpfull for my concept,but i found another answer like this,code is here

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$current_date=date('Y-m-d');//current london time
$current_datetime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dateTimeUK = new DateTime($current_datetime, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$dateTimeUK->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$dateTimeIST= $dateTimeUK->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');//india time