# PHP Time Conversion Exercise

Tags: php

I am trying to solve this exercise in PHP from a Python book

Write a program that converts a time from one time zone to another. The user enters the time
in the usual American way, such as 3:48pm or 11:26am. The first time zone the user enters
is that of the original time and the second is the desired time zone. The possible time zones
are Eastern, Central, Mountain, or Pacific.
Time: 11:48pm
Starting zone: Pacific
Ending zone: Eastern
2:48am

Struggling to come with a logic to solve it.

At the moment I am thinking about

```
IF AM
    Switch
       16 different cases
IF PM
    Switch
       16 different cases
```

but it seems a stupid way of doing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Write a function to convert from source time to UTC, and another from UTC to target time. PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class can make this trivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timezone conversion in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505681/timezone-conversion-in-php)

Comment: You don't need 16 different cases. You just need to know each zone's offset from UTC. Then you can calculate the difference in offsets, and adjust the time by that.

Comment: Thanks! My brain is clearly not working!